# Ajax call always runs success function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i want to verify user_id and mobile number from server (php) . when i enter  wrong user_id and mobile number so every time ajax is execute success (if) part rather than else part.

**my ajax is**

```
         <script>
          $(document).ready(function() {
          $("#b").click(function(){
          var user_id=$('#user_id').val();
          var mobile=$("#mobile").val();
                    $.ajax({
                            type:"POST",
                            url:"http://localhost/test.php",
                            data:{user_id:user_id, mobile:mobile},
                              success:function(response){
                                if(response="valid"){
                                    alert(response);
                                    window.location='https://www.google.co.in';
                                }
                                else{
                                    alert("invalid");
                                }                       

                              },
                              error:function(response){
                                alert("error");
                              }
                          });       

                });  
              });

</script>
```

**my php code**

```
 <?php
  $user_id=$_POST['user_id'];
  $mobile=$_POST['mobile'];
  $con=@mysql_connect("localhost","root","")or die('connection failed: ' . mysql_error());
  $db=mysql_select_db("sorethroat");  
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `myfieldmembers` where `employee_id`='".$user_id."' && `mobile`='".$mobile."'");
    if($result === FALSE) { 
        die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
    }
    if(mysql_num_rows ($result)>0) {
      echo "valid";
    } else {
      echo"invalid";
    }

 ?>
```

on server side after hard-code this php is working fine

Comment: this is an assignment `if(response="valid")` it should be a comparison `if(response=="valid")`

Comment: This purely shows lack of efforts before posting this looking at this line of code if(response="valid"){

Comment: now else part executing every time :(

Answer (score 1):

`response="valid"` change to `response=="valid"`

Comment: after correction like response=="valid" now else part is executing  every login time where i'm wrong :( ?

Comment: yep yes i entered right username and password as well wrong in both condition it execute else part like invalid

Comment: alert(response); in else condition too. also try to modify the php code to    if(mysql_num_rows ($result)>0) {
      echo "valid";
    } else {
      echo mysql_num_rows ($result);
    } so you can find  out the problems on php side not

Comment: thanks for replying and your comment is very helpful.. i did echo in else part in php file like  else { echo mysql_num_rows ($result); } and i put alert(response) in ajax else too.. so after wrong input it alert 0 that is good . and after right input it alert valid it is also good but it directly entered in else part of ajax with right message . i mean response is directly entered in else part ..

Comment: i have solved the problem with puting integer  1 for valid and 0 for not in both side i mean in php file as well in ajax :D

Answer (score 0):

You have solved it by replacing valid/invalid with 1/0, so it is working now.

For people who run into the same problem and are not able to replace with 0/1:

Check the length of the `response`.
Sometimes spaces get added, in that case your when checking values on screen it will look like you are comparing "phrase" == "phrase" but your code will compare "phrase" == " phrase" (notice the space), which is not the same.

After having had to deal with this problem myself, I am using this by default

```
response = response.trim();
```

Comment: yeah you are right i have done with for replacing 1/0 . it is working :D